# Running time of algorithms

Tags: performance, big-o

In this algorithm

```
int j=1;
while (j<=n/2) {
    int i=1;
    while (i <= j) {
        cout << j << " "<< i << endl;
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    j++;
}
```

Would the running time of this algorithm be T(n)=(n^2/2)+n+4

```
for (int i=2; i <=n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j <= n;) {
        cout << i << " "<< j << endl;
        j=j+(n/4);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

It would be T(n)=(n-2)^2+2

Answer (score 0):

for the first one. T(n)=sum of number from 1 to n/2 because, the outer loop while be entered n/2 times and for those n/2 times the inner loop will enter 1 time and first turn, 2 times and the 2nd turn, 3 times at the 3rd turn...

> T(n) = ((n/2)/2) * ((n/2)+1) =  n/4 * (n/2+1) = n/4 * ((n+2)/2)

**Maybe you can simplify it more by doing the multiplication.**

The 2nd one. T(n) = (n+1) * (n/4) because the outer loop will enter n+1 times and for each of those times the inner loop will enter n/4 times.

> T(n) = (n+1) * (n/4)

Comment: so the first one would be T(n)= (n/2)+n?

Comment: no it will be: n/4*(n/2+1) because the summation formula between 1 and x is (x/2)*(x+1) example: 1 to 10 = 10/2*11 = 5*11 = 55

Comment: I am putting the pieces together, but I am starting to get it.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd one, the loop increment is proportional to the loop end point.  The number of iterations doesn't increase with n, only the range of values.  Starting from `j=0`, it takes at most 5 increments of `j+=(n/4)` for `j <= n` to become false.  (Only 4 if n is a multiple of 4).  Either way, this is O(1).

So the 2nd version's inner loop does ~5 operations, and there's a `cout << endl` outside the loop, so each iteration of the outer loop does ~6 print operations.  (If they're to a terminal, it will only be line-buffered, so count cost by number of lines printed = number of system calls.  If it's going to a file, it'll be block buffered by default, so cost ~= number of operations ~= number of 4k blocks of data printed.)

The 2nd version's outer loop runs from i=2 .. n, so it runs n-1 times, printing 6 lines each time.  (or 5 if `n%4 == 0`).  T(loop2) = 6n.

Hassan's analysis looks ok for the first loop.